# Making Odata Saves without the response

Tags: objective-c, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

Just wondering if there is anyway to save data across the line without the response coming back. i.e. Im using the objc odata sdk. If I create an employee entity on the ipad, than I save it, I dont need to receive the the saved entity back. So really its sending the data across the line than returning it for no reason. Only really need to send it across.

Any ideas on how I can set saves to be push to server and not have to wait for the return?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest CTP (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx) you can use the Prefer header. The client can send the request with Prefer header set to return-no-content and the server will send an empty response back. The header is described here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-http-prefer-01.

Comment: Hi Vitek, Thanks for your response. Is there any examples anywhere of a http request being sent with the Prefer Header? Ive added the PreFer header with a value of return-no-content and it does not seem to take effect (Im also using the October CTP release of WCF data services). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In order for the Prefer header to work, the request must be a V3 request, so make sure that you also send DataServiceVersion: 3.0; header with it. (This was necessary to maintain backward compatiblity correctly).

Comment: And the server must allow V3, so don't forget to set config.MaxProtocolVersion = V3.